# installing libtsmux-dev and flutsmux on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, libraries, streaming, gstreamer, fluendo

I wanted to install the *libtsmux-dev* and then *flutsmux* on this version but it seems this library is removed since executing **sudo apt-get install libtsmux-dev** gives me this error:

```
 E: Unable to locate package libtsmux-dev
```

I also tried to install *libtsmux-dev* from here:

http://freecode.com/projects/libtsmux

and followed the instructions for *flutsmux* from here:

https://core.fluendo.com/gstreamer/trac/wiki/HowToBuildFromSvn

but still gst-launch-0.10 (for a simple pipeline) says there is no element "flutsmux"!

FYI I'm using this pipeline code:

```
 gst-launch -e videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=25/1, width=640, \
 height=360 ! x264enc ! flutsmux ! \
 filesink location=test.ts
```

can you please help me with it? what shall I do to be able to use flutsmux in my pipeline?

Thanks in advance!